# Linear Oscillator Frequency Problem

Tags: oscillator, remote-control, integrator, loop-gain

I was doing one of the problem sets when I stumbled upon this gem.

[image]

I know that for oscillation to occur, the gain has to be greater than 1.

The loop gain I computed is

[image]

Could anyone suggest any approach towards the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Might be worth working out the oscillation frequency first, as the question suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your gain calculations are wrong: should contain terms: R/(1+RCs), 2R/(1+2RCs), 1/2RCs and, of course, gm

Derive the closed loop transfer function, which is 3rd order. For steady-state oscillation the denominator of the CLTF must factorise to the form: (s^2 + wn^2)(s + a), where wn is the resonant frequency in rad/sec. The transient, e^-at, decays to zero, leaving the steady-state sinusoid at wn rad/sec. Compare TF denominator coefficients to find the values of wn and gm

Rough calculation gives: wn = 1/RCsqrt(2); gm = sqrt(3/2)/R, but these need checking.

The above is based on the observation that the denominator of the closed loop TF of a 3rd order system can be written: (As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D), which can be simplified by dividing throughout by A, giving the form (s^3 + Ps^2 + Qs + R). Note that the denominator of the CLTF represents the characteristic equation; the numerator only serves to augment the natural behaviour.

The relative stability of a 3rd order CLTF can be determined by comparing the products of the inner two coefficients and the outer two coefficients. Thus, BC>AD = stable; BC=AD = critically stable (i.e. sinusoidal); BC < AD = unstable. This is a pretty useful design ROT for 3rd order systems generally.

So, taking the simplified TF and setting the sinusoidal condition, PQ=R, gives the denominator TF: (s^3 + Ps^2 + Qs + PQ) and this factorises to (s^2 + Q)(s + P), which immediately gives the resonant frequency as wn=sqrt(Q) rad/sec

Comment: Question to Chu: How can I derive a closed-loop transfer function without any input?

Comment: @LvW, that's a very good question. I view an oscillator as a feedback system with a set-point (input demand) of zero. Since the configuration is critically stable, the smallest disturbance, however it may arise, will invoke the complementary function solution (or 'homogeneous solution') of the differential equation.

Comment: I know what you mean - and, yes, the denominator will be independent on the node at which such a disturbance is injected. Nevertheless, mentioning a closed-loop tzransfer function with out definition of input and output can create some confusion. Don`t you agree that analyzing the loop gain is much more efficient and easy to understand?

Comment: @LvW, Possibly. Perhaps I've been a control engineer too long! But it's good to have a different perspective on problems. I wasn't sure that the gain/phase method would work properly, given that the system is 3rd order. What answers do you get?

Comment: @LvW, just checked - same results for wn and gm as TF method, so two answers for the price of one today!

Comment: Chu-however, I am sure that the closed-loop method does not work always because it reveals only cases instability which are not always identical to oscillations. However, the loop gain method does reflect the oscillation condition (Barkhausen) and is unambigiously.

Comment: But it IS a negative feedback closed loop system. The values of gm and wn are exactly the same as those predicted by your method. And saying that the TF method only reveals special modes is simply wrong.

Comment: Did I speak of "special modes"? It is a fact that (a) the closed-loop method reveals instability and (b) that instability is NOT always identical with oscillations. Something wrong?

Comment: 'reveals only cases of instability ...' looks like special cases to me. If you bother to read my analysis you will see that stable, unstable and critically stable conditions are identified.

Comment: Please, read and quote my comments carefully. My concern was (and still is) that unstable conditions are NOT identical with oscillatory behaviour. There are other cases of instability (latch-up, for example).

Comment: But the case AD=BC is critically stable and that is the condition for an oscillator, and the results I gave for frequency of oscillation and corresponding gm value are clearly referenced to this condition. My analysis included the unstable and stable conditions merely to expand a little on the original question posed by the OP and to highlight how simple inspection of a 3rd order TF can yield some useful information on a system. Further, I read your comment: 'the closed loop method does not work'; well it does work - your comment is positively misleading to those who may read these pages.

Comment: OK - let us stop this discussion at this point. One final correction - you forgot one important word in your quotation: "always" ("the closed loop method does not work always").

Comment: Within the scope of the original question, and assuming linear systems, and also without nuances of the technology, such as latch-up, tell me when the closed loop method does not work.

Comment: I think, I have answered this already: Instability - even in case of a 3rd-order system - does not necessarily means: oscillation.

Comment: That would require a negative coefficient in the TF, which is clearly unstable

Comment: Yes - if you see it from a pure theoretical point of view. However, in practice there are cases with positive coefficients but with a pole in the RHP which is responsible for instabiliy (without oscillating).

Comment: Do you have an example with a real pole in the RHP and all positive coefficients?

Comment: Yes - a modification of the WIEN oscillator. Based on the rules of a tuned bridge you can swap the elements of each path (positive and the negative feedback) without disturbing the tuned condition. Hence, the new circuit (2nd order) still is in accordance with Barkhausens oscillation condition - and the circuit will oscillate, provided an IDEAL operational amplifier is used. However, if a real opamp is used (simply modelled as a first-order lowpass) the oscillation condition still can be met, but the finite gain introduces one single positive pole into the system causing immediate latch-up.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the last case (real opamp model) is,of course, a 3rd-order system.

Comment: That's totally off-topic. Your criticism is that the closed-loop method does not work in the analysis of the oscillator which is the topic of this post. Introducing a completely different oscillator is a straw man.

Comment: Last comment from my side: 4 comments back you have asked for an example with a real pole in the RHP. I gave you one example. Really off-topic?

Comment: Yes - not the oscillator under discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes my approach: It is a straighforward procedure based on the oscillation condition.

1.) Remember the oscillation condition: Loop gain real and (slightly) larger than unity (real means: Loop phase=0).

2.) Determine the loop gain A(loop) correctly. For each FET stage: Gain A=-gm*Z (Z:parallel combination). For convinience: Set R||(1/sC)=1/(sC+1/R)

3.) It turns out that the **numerator** of the 3rd-order loop gain function will be real and negative. Hence, for a real loop gain function the **denominator** also must be real and negative.

4.) This leads to the condition: **Im(denominator)=0** (after setting s=jw). This equation gives you the oscillation frequency. The result will be a very simple expression.

5.) With this frequency you can determine the value of gm which makes the remaining real part equal to (or slightly larger than) unity.